# nginx: How do I map a domain to a path in another domain without redirects?

Tags: nginx

I have a domain like so:

http://source.com

And I need to map it to a particular url from another domain on the same server:

http://target.com/source

Is this possible without redirecting the source?  How do I specify this in a server directive in nginx?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the proxy pass directive.  Example:

```
server {

    listen 80;
    server_name  source.com;

location / {
    proxy_next_upstream     error timeout invalid_header http_500;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header Host source.com;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_pass http://target.com/source/;
    }
}
```

There's more documentation on the nginx wiki here:  http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpProxyModule#proxy_pass

Comment: This is it!  I was beginning to think it was impossible.

Answer (score 0):

When you say you do not want to redirect, I take this to mean you want the "source" url to remain in the address bar but for the files to be served from the "source" folder in "target".

As long as target is on the same server, you can simply just specify the root for source to point to the relevant folder.

```
server {
    server_name source.com;
    root /var/www/target.com/public_html/source;
    location / {
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: Sorry, it's not just a local directory, it's a dynamic request.